# dart2js build 'file:///Users/'

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

When I do a dart2js build, the bootstrap.dart.js javascript reference's my file system a lot. If you do a search for 'file:///Users/' within the file it shows the file system path of the build user. This means I get file not found errors on other machines. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen. Maybe you got some import paths wrong. It's hard to tell as you provided not enough information.

Comment: I'm not sure what other information I need to provide for this one. I assumed it wasn't meant to happen.... All imports are correct. The error seems to be every 'component' that I import?

Comment: I understand. Package layout, pubspec.yaml, how your import statements look like, how you call `dart2js` (from which directory you start it and the options you use)